# Can't boot 12.10 after installing nvidia proprietary drivers

Tags: boot-failure

I was having issues with the 304 nvidia drivers, so I decided to downgrade to the 295 drivers. I did so by dropping out of X, stopping lightdm, and installing the drivers. However, now my computer won't boot into Ubuntu at all. It hangs on

```
stopping anac(h)cronistic cron
```

and nothing happens. I have to manually shut it off. Booting into failsafeX mode doesn't work either. I'm writing this from a live USB because I can't figure out what else to do. Any ideas? Is there a way to purge the nvidia files while booted into the live USB?

Answer (score 1):

If it's completely dead (no terminal/console by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> then you might need to boot off your LiveUSB and then chroot into the hard drive.

First, boot off the LiveUSB and open a terminal window.  Next mount the Ubuntu root partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

You'll need to change sda1 to be your actual Ubuntu boot partition.  Have a look at:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

if you're not sure. Next, export the LiveCD filesystem to the root filesystem on the drive:

```
sudo mount ‐‐bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount ‐‐bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount ‐‐bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Now change the root filesystem to the hard disk:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

No re-install the nouveau driver:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Then reboot and try again.

It might also be useful to remove the troublesome modules eg:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

or

```
sudo a-t-get remove nvidia-current-updates
```